# CSS - Styling in Mozilla different then Google Chrome

Tags: css

When I edited the header CSS in my Chrome browser everything is centered, when I open it in Firefox it's not.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

What am I doing wrong in the styling settings? The website is:

https://www.thefixedgearshop.com

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Yes, part of posting a quality question is to abstract out the problem code (so as to remove environmental issues) put it in a jsfiddle so the problem can be reproduced, then putting the code in your question so we can read your code.

Answer (score -1):

Did you use some prefix like -webkit- ? It would works only for Chrome, safari or android.

Here's the list :

- -o- : Opera
- -moz- Gecko (Mozilla)
- -webkit- Webkit (Chrome, Safari, Android...)
- -ms- Microsoft (Internet Explorer)

Or you can still check the compatibily of your CSS feature on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/)

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!